# Rounded inverse shape TextView Android

Tags: android, textview, shapes, rounded-corners

How can you make the shape of the edges in Android TextView so that the result is like the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to make any sophisticated shapes like this. It would simply suffice to make `image` looking like this (i.e. label's background). Or you can make "blue dot" with white outline so in the end visually you will get result like pictured.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a file with the name of rounded_corners.xml in the /res/drawable folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
    <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />

    </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- White Top color -->
    <item android:bottom="3px">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />


    </shape>

    </item>

    </layer-list>
```

and specify this in the textbox as the background drawable

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
             />
```

hope this helps!